# How to use child_added correctly in react/firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm not entirely sure this is the right way to go about it but I am trying to append to my firebase database different messages that a user might receive.

I have this function that is called when I click a button:

```
sendMessageButtonClicked: function(){
      var loggedInUser = this.state.loggedInUserObject;
      var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users/' + loggedInUser.useruid + '/messages/');
      databaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
        var messageBodyValue = document.getElementById('message').value;
        var chat = snapshot.val();
        var msg = document.getElementById('msgs');
        msg.appendChild(messageBodyValue);
      })
    },
```

But I am getting the error:

```
failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

I can confirm messageBodyValue is what ever i type in e.g. 'hello'
chat is an object with 3 properties
msg is an id.

so i am trying to append a child to this html element every time I send it.

I want my firebase JSON to go from:

```
 "messages" : {
        "PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2" : {
          "messageBody" : "Hello, how are you?",
          "receiverName" : "Lucy",
          "receiverUseruid" : "PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2"
        }
```

to:

```
  "messages" : {
        "PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2" : {
          "messageBody" : "Hello, how are you?",
          "messageBody" : "another msg",
          "messageBody" : "another child message",
          "receiverName" : "Lucy",
          "receiverUseruid" : "PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `messageBodyValue` inside a DOM node before passing it into [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

```
var messageBodyValue = document.getElementById('message').value;
var messageElement = document.createTextNode(messageBodyValue);
var msg = document.getElementById('msgs');
msg.appendChild(messageElement);
```

This shouldn't be affecting the structure of the data in your Firebase instance, but it looks like there might be a problem with the way you're trying to store the data.

```
"PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2" : {
  "messageBody" : "Hello, how are you?",
  "messageBody" : "another msg",
  "messageBody" : "another child message",
  "receiverName" : "Lucy",
  "receiverUseruid" : "PHS2DwlCZ0RJaylhJ0FNgEiNLug2"
}
```

An object can't have multiple `messageBody` properties.

Instead, you'd have to get hold of the `messageBody` ref, then [`push`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) further values onto it.